# How to grab Drop-down list VALUE instead of INDEX, via POST

Tags: php, html, post

I have a form on a PHP page that has a drop-down list and a submit button. I'm sending the selected drop down choice data via POST.

Now, when I try to grab this data on another page. I only get the "index" (eg: 1 or 2 or 3 etc.) of the drop-down list and not its actual "value". Is there any way, I can make my PHP page send the value as POST data instead?

Comment: Can you link some code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am sure that you did not give value for drop down options.
See this

```
<select name="select">
<option value="Option 1" selected>Option 1</option>
<option value="Option 2">Option 2</option>
<option value="Option 3">Option 3</option>
<option value="Option 4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

Now try posting and get value

http://www.abbeyworkshop.com/howto/lamp/php-listbox/index.html

Comment: Ah ... you are right. Worked right away. I tried accepting your answer but it tells me to wait 7 mins. I'll accept then. Appreciate the help buddy!